# Google Maps Z-index map doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, google-maps, z-index

My website has z-index from 100 to 1000.
Google map brings gm-style div with a z-index of 0.

All google api z-index, talks about marker z-index.. how can I make the map itself visible?

I tried to add css for .gm-style z-index, with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add a higher z-index to your map-canvas div, if other elements are stacked on top of it. This will start a new stacking context, so that items inside the google map (even with a z-index of 0) will still be visible. More information on stacking contexts [here](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/).

Also, have you added a height to your map-canvas div in your CSS? Without a height, the google map will not show.

Try adding this to your CSS file:

```
#map-canvas {
    height: 500px;
    z-index: 1001;
}
```

If this doesn't help, please include a link to the page you're working on so I can see if something else is the problem.

Comment: the height was my problem!

Comment: Had a hunch it would be that! Still catches me out sometimes.

Comment: thanks! I dont know if I can or not ask here, but I dont want to open another question just for that.
now onto the map, I get 2 attributes from CouchDB views ( {{start}} and {{end}} points ) I need to transform them from strings to LatLng, ideas?

Comment: Different question = new question :)